# How to use Storyblok field level translations in a multiple domains setup?

Tags: multilingual, storyblok

I a website with multiple domains (1 domain per locale) where only the content changes.

The content is served by Storyblok.

I'd like to use Field level translations as most of my content is the same for each domain / language (as opposed to folder level translations).

I read and applied the guide on how to proceed with Field level translations and it works ok, except that in the visual editor, it adds a prefix for each language in the URL when I switch languages (which results in a 404)

E.g.:

switching from example.com/about.html Engligh to French, adds /fr-FR to the path, thus resulting in a 404.

in short, I'd like to have one language per domain + field level translations without prefixing the URLs with the locale code in the visual editor.

I've heard about the "Advanced paths" plugin in Storyblok, but it seems Storyblok restricts access to that plugin for the "Teams" plan, with a high pricing bump (from $90 to $500+)

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks

I asked the question to Storyblok customer service and reading some articles.